# Aligning H3 tag and icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a h3 element with a font awesome icon and I just can't get them to play nicely.  there seem to be quite a few questions along these lines but I can't seem to extrapolate what I need.

If you see the below the info icon is aligned below the text.  I've tried a number of things to sort it out and I've failed.  Now I'm hoping someone may take pity and point out what I need to do ?

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <h3 style="display:inline;">The monkey talks!</h3>
  <span id="terminatorinfoIcon" class="fa-stack d-inline-block">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to the header:

```css
h3{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="display:inline-block">
  <h3 style="display:inline;">The monkey talks!</h3>
  <span id="terminatorinfoIcon" class="fa-stack d-inline-block">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it flex container and use align-items

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="display:flex; align-items: center; " >
  <h3 style="display:inline;">The monkey talks!</h3>
  <span id="terminatorinfoIcon" class="fa-stack d-inline-block">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I have accepted the other answer as the answer as it is more specific to the issue but I suspect this is the better long term approach...)

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox with `align-items: center`:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <h3>The monkey talks!</h3>
  <span class="fa-stack d-inline-block">
     <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```